# How to maintain scroll position of listview when the adapter update

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, android-scrollview, android-scroll

I am bind the adapter with listview and at first I have fetch 10 records then when I scroll ends then again the items added in listview and it works perfect.

But when I added items after scroll end then at that time items are added successfully then the listview position set to top. I want to set that position to new added items.

Here is my codes:

onscroll function:

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {               
    new items().execute();
}
```

Async function:

```
class items extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        ...
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", String.valueOf(id)));

        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET",
                params);


        try {


            for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                Product item = new Product(name, imageurl);
                product_name.add(item);

            }

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
    pDialog.dismiss();


    adapter = new CategoryAdapter(context, product_name);

    category_linear.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Baseadapter:

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;

    // protected List<String> m_List;
    protected List<Product> rowItems;

    public CategoryAdapter(Context context, List<Product> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.rowItems = items;
    }

    public void addItemAll(List<Product> item) {
        //
        rowItems.addAll(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return rowItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return rowItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
                    R.layout.row, null);

        }

        Product rowItem = (Product) getItem(position);

        TextView text = ViewHolderPattern.get(convertView, R.id.item_name);

        text.setText(rowItem.getTitle());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Now how can I set the position of scroll while new items is added.

currently when new items added then it will go to top of the listview.

But I want to set the position to the new items starting.

How can I do this?

Comment: Get position of item that is visible on top of list using getFirstVisiblePosition() in your onScroll call back. And set it again in onPostExecute() callback using setSelection() method.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of the adapter every time you execute the code in the AsyncTask. i.e in your onPostExecute function. Instead of doing

```
adapter = new CategoryAdapter(context, product_name);
category_linear.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You should be doing

```
adapter.addItemAll(product_name);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Also write the following

```
adapter = new CategoryAdapter(context, new List<Product>());
category_linear.setAdapter(adapter);
```

just after you instantiate your ListView to make it work.

The data will be updated in your list and your position will remain the same.

Cheers!

Comment: what's the error in logcat? Also can you try after removing notifyDataSetChanged() from addItemAll function in the adapter.

Comment: logcat : `fragment.CategoryFragment$items.onPostExecute(CategoryFragment.java:248)
fragment.CategoryFragment$items.onPostExecute(CategoryFragment.java:1)
 at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
 at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
`

Comment: updated the answer, please have a look if it solves the purpose. Also is it the whole error from the logcat? or you missed something from the top?

Comment: There should have been some exception listed somewhere like NullPointerException or something?

Comment: That means your adapter is coming null. Should be resolved if you instantiate your adapter in this fragment once in onViewCreated and assign that adapter to the listview.

Comment: You will need to update the relevant code of initialization of listview and adapter here.